# How to replace node in post compiler in typescript

Tags: typescript

I wont to create plugin compiler that replace some code.

For example, I have this method:

```
foo(){
  doSomthing()
}
```

I wont to replace the `doSomthing()` with `doSomthingElse()`.

So, assume that i get into the node that i need to replace, how do i actual replace it?

```
const visitor: ts.Visitor = (node: ts.Node): ts.VisitResult => {
  if (needToReplace(node))
    // What i need to do here?

  return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, ctx)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I need a bit more information. Are you saying you want to conditionally evaluate two different methods, or override an existing one?

Comment: override existing one...